# Wix Error in action CommitIIS7ConfigTransaction

Tags: wix, failed-installation

Environment Details: Installation package is created via a TFS continuous integration build process (using Wix 3.10.3) that has an agent on the deployment test server (A TFS user is running as a service on the release box) where I am having the issue below.  Package is downloaded and installed via the release agent of TFS using the powershell function (NOT powershell on targeted machine) with this script, which runs the installation in admin mode if not already in admin mode.

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{
    Echo "This script needs to be run As Admin"
    Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -file [ps1file]' -verb RunAs
    Break
}
else
{
    Echo "Running as Admin"
    MSIEXEC /i "[PathToMSI]" /qn /L*v "[PathToLog]" INSTALLDIR="[INSTALLPATH]" WEBAPPNAME="[Name]" AUTHMETHOD="[METHOD]" [SQLCONNECTIONPROPERTIES...]
    Echo "Script complete"
}
```

First off I can install this product without issue the first time on the server in question, it is the updates that are producing strange behavior.  The agent automated update produces this text with no discernible error code, minus the generic 1603.

```
Action start 11:20:45: CommitIIS7ConfigTransaction.
MSI (s) (74!18) [11:20:45:585]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ConfigureIIs7Exec property. Its value is '**********'.
MSI (s) (74!18) [11:20:45:585]: Doing action: ConfigureIIs7Exec
MSI (s) (74:34) [11:20:45:632]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (74:34) [11:20:45:632]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (74:34) [11:20:45:632]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (74:34) [11:20:45:632]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (74:34) [11:20:45:632]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (74:34) [11:20:45:632]: Unlocking Server
MSI (s) (74:34) [11:20:45:632]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (74:34) [11:20:45:632]: Product: MyProduct -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (74:34) [11:20:45:632]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: MyProduct . Product Version: 1.1.1.1. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Me. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

But when I run this update manually I get this error:

```
MSI (s) (34!1C) [16:27:41:979]: Doing action: StartIIS7ConfigTransaction
MSI (s) (34!1C) [16:27:41:979]: Product: MyProduct -- Error 26031. Failed to schedule transaction for changes to IIS.  (-2147418113         )

MSI (s) (34:48) [16:27:41:994]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (34:48) [16:27:41:994]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (34:48) [16:27:41:994]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (34:48) [16:27:41:994]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (34:48) [16:27:41:994]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (34:48) [16:27:41:994]: Unlocking Server
MSI (s) (34:48) [16:27:42:010]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (34:48) [16:27:42:010]: Product: MyProduct -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (34:48) [16:27:42:010]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: MyProduct. Product Version: 1.1.1.1. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Me. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

I have scoured this and other forums looking for any indication of how to fix it, but have yet to turn up anything related to this specific error code/text. I have exhausted all options I could think of over the last few days.  Any help would be appreciated.